# what is Django formsets used for?

Tags: python, django, web

I found something strange in Django's documentation which is called *formset*, [see it here](http://web.archive.org/web/20140403200450/https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/formsets/).
I am wondering *What is `formset` used for* and *How to use it*?

Comment: It's gonna be tough for anyone to give a better explanation than the docs give themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formset is an example of datagrid .
If you want to use multiple form of same type at one page.you can use Formset.
Example :

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username", "email"]
```

Now if you want to use `UserForm` multiple times at one page you need to use Formset.

```
from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory
Uforms = formset_factory(UserForm, extra = 4)  #extra used to define how many empty forms will display
```

Into Your views.py

```
def submit(request):
    if request.POST:
        #code to manage post request
        # validation to formset you can follow django docs
    else:
        address_formSet = Uforms(instance=UserForm())
    # render response
```

Template code

```
      {{ address_formset.as_table }}
```

You can follow step by step [django formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/formsets/) to learn.

## Example Code

```
class Address(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=48)
    zipcode = models.IntegerField(max_length=5)  

class Friend(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address)
```

## forms.py

```
 
from django import forms
from .models import Address, Friend
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory

MAX_ADDRESS = 2   #updated
AddressFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Address, Friend, extra=MAX_ADDRESS)   #updated

class UserAddressForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
```

## view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from .models import *
from .forms import UserSubmittedAddressForm, AddressFormSet

def submit(request):
    if request.POST:
        #Logic
    else:
        form = UserAddressForm()
        address_formSet = AddressFormSet(instance=Address())
    # render response
```

## template code

```
      {{ form.as_table }}
      {{ address_formset.as_table }}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's used to work with e.g. a table of records. It's a way to create data grid functionality in such a way that Django does all the heavy lifting (all data for all the records are sent back in the same POST).